# Should `.bundle` directory be added to CVS?

Tags: ruby, git, bundler, gitignore

Recently I moved some of my Ruby project dependencies to `development` group to not to install them on production environments (like `rubocop`)

And in those projects I see that there is new file `.bundle/config` with content like this:

```
---
BUNDLE_WITH: "development"
```

Or

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development"
```

I think I can safely add this file (and `.bundle`) folder to `.gitignore`, but to be sure - is there any best practice for that?

Could not find any useful info on `$PROJECT_ROOT/.bundle` directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Don't store the .bundle directory in source. It's intended to be a local cache of certain bundler settings and flags, rather than something shared between all project contributors.

### Analysis

There are some arguments for and against storing your Gemfile.lock in source control, but the contents of the .bundle directory are not intended to be shared across multiple users/machines within a project. The only potential use case for tracking .bundle/config is to remember certain flags across runs in a production or testing branch, but [that behavior is deprecated](https://bundler.io/whats_new.html#cli-deprecations) anyway.

Pragmatically, storing the .bundle directory may lead to unintended flag usage by your fellow developers. This is likely to lead to unnecessary debugging efforts, and potentially-surprising behavior for project contributors. A Rake task or setup/deployment script is a better option for handling Bundler flags, especially as this behavior is deprecated and is scheduled to go away in Bundler 3.